# Contenteditable cursor move back to beginning in ngfor loop

Tags: javascript, angular, angular7, contenteditable

Contenteditable cursor move back to beginning when I use [innerhtml] to bind html data inside ngFor.

```
<div *ngFor="article of articleLists">
  <div id="editor_article_{{article.id}}" contenteditable="true" [innerHtml]="article.data" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" placeholder="type your text here..."(input)="editableData($event.target.innerHTML, article.id, '')">
  </div>
</div>
```

But if I declare variable in component and bind [innerhtml], contenteditable text direction is fine. But the problem is that variable should be dynamic to bind inside ngFor.

Comment: You'll have to keep track of the caret position by yourself. The content inside `ngFor` is rebuilt every time the loop is executed. You can get some inspiration on how to handle the cursor on this site: https://codepen.io/neoux/pen/OVzMor

Answer (score 0):

You may need to give more context around your question:

- When you are interacting with your web page, at what point does the *"contenteditable cursor move back to beginning"*?
- What would you like to happen exactly?

Either way, I am going to take a bit of a guess at what might happening....

---

Something may be causing the array `articleLists` to be updated in such a way that the reference of each object changes. This then appears to be a "new object" to Angular since it tracks objects by their reference. Therefore Angular will re-render the contents of the `*ngFor` loop and the caret position is lost.

One way to retain the caret (or cursor) position would be to prevent Angular re-rendering the contents of `*ngFor` (when it does not need to). This can be done by changing the way Angular identifies each object, using the trackBy function.

```js
articleLists = [
  {
    id: 1,
    data: 'This is article 1',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    data: 'This is article 2',
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    data: 'This is article 3',
  },
]

trackElement(index: number, element: any) {
  return element ? element.guid : null;
}
```

```html
<div *ngFor="article of articleLists; trackBy: trackElement">
  <div id="editor_article_{{article.id}}" contenteditable="true" [innerHtml]="article.data" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" placeholder="type your text here..."(input)="editableData($event.target.innerHTML, article.id, '')">
  </div>
</div>
```

Now if the references to the objects in the list change, but the id's stay the same, Angular will **not** re-render the whole list.

I learnt this from this article [here](https://malcoded.com/posts/angular-ngfor/).